# tax deduction for 30k loan

Tags: united-states, taxes, loans, tax-deduction, capital-loss

I recently sold my condo.  I sold it for less than I owed but took out a 30k loan to pay off the difference (traditional sale, NOT a short sale).

Are there any tax breaks or deductions I can take for this loan?

Do I take them now or after the loan is paid off?

Comment: I'm not sure the loan is relevant but I'd imagine the loss on the property would be deductible.

Comment: Are you in the U.S.? Tax law is quite different depending on your jurisdiction.

Comment: yes, the condo was in Chicago, IL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loan itself is not tax deductible; unless you took it as part of a mortgage, anyway, it's just a regular loan.  Mortgage and Student Loan Interest deductions are special cases explicitly given tax-deductible status; other loans are not deductible (unless part of a business expense or other qualifying reason).

If this were a short sale (which you note it was not but included for completeness' sake), and some of your debt was cancelled, that may have tax implications.

You [cannot take a capital loss](https://www.irs.gov/uac/What-if-I-sell-my-home-for-a-loss%3F) on your personal residence, so the loss itself is not deductible.

Comment: -1 to US tax law